# OSX High Sierra: Bluetooth audio mutes when a video ends in browser?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, high-sierra

Using iTunes or Spotify to play music through bluetooth headphones. While the music is playing, I watch a YouTube video in Safari. When the video ends, the music is muted. I can see in the music app that it is still playing, just muted.

This only happens when using Bluetooth audio. Built-in speakers behave as expected.

This only started happening since I upgraded to High Sierra.

Macbook Pro
OSX High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88)
Bose Wireless SoundSport headphones

Answer (score 1):

Some of these issues seemed to go away when I updated the firmware on my Bose headphones to 1.3.4.